# Mouseover and click event on map

Tags: dictionary

I have a task to show some details when mouseover a region on map, and also bind the click event on the map. It is not on the marker. I searched in google map api but did not found any event for this. How can this task should be done.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question right, There are two ways to do this.

1) Drawing transparent polygons for regions in the maps and add a mouseover event to those polygons.

2) Track the lat,long of the mouse pointer and use a logic to customise your click event.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create event listeners.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(variable, 'mouseevent', function () {
  ***WHAT YOU WANT TO DO HERE
});
```

Not sure the specifics you are aiming for so here is an example of mouseover & mouseout events:

[Here is a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jeremyhawes/mdxe4x44/)

```
google.maps.event.addListener(your_polygon, 'mouseover', function() {
       your_polygon.setOptions({
         fillOpacity: 0.4,
         strokeOpacity: 0.6
       });
       google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(your_marker, 'mouseover', function(){
          infoBubble5.open(map, your_marker_icon);
       });
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(your_polygon, 'mouseout', function() {
       desert_parks5.setOptions({
         fillOpacity: 0.6,
         strokeOpacity: 0.8
       });
  });
```

You could change mouseover in the marker to 'click' if you like too.